# Bootstrap img-responsive doesn't work, picture is still longer than screen

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active col-xs-12">
      <img src="big1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="...">
    </div>

    <div class="item col-xs-12">
      <img src="big1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="...">
    </div>

    <div class="item col-xs-12">
      <img src="big1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="...">
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried to search, but nothing solved my problem. I do not want to use display: table, as I read in similar question. Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: Im not seeing any issue, here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/n1up4xog/ Do you have any custom css that you are using for your carousel

Comment: @Steve K No, I do not have any custom css, it scales fine if the screen is very small.

Comment: If you drag the window larger in the fiddle demo that i shared you can see that the image never breaks the container so there has to be some other issue than your markup because I used the exact same markup that you used except I added a couple of closing div tags that you are missing.

Comment: can you post your screenshot ?@Kateryna

Answer (score 1):

Change `.img-responsive` inside bootstrap.css to the following:

```
.img-responsive {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

For some reason adding width: 100% to the mix makes `img-responsive` work. It also work in Firefox as well as Chrome.

and also try this :

```
.item img {
  width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the this line in your CSS file to fix the problem:

```
.img-responsive{ width:100% !Important;}
```

Comment: did not worked for me. When I scale picture more - img-responsive works ok, but if I try to scale just a little bit - picture is too long

Answer (score 0):

To keep your image responsive you better used

```
img{
  max-width: 100%
}
```

as per your comment it seems like this css is been overwritten by some other css, so you can use css specificity here like below

```
img, .container img.img-responsive{
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

this will keep your img inside your screen size and this is common technique we used to keep our images responsive

Comment: In inspect element it shows like crossed img{
  max-width: 100%
}, but my main css file goes after bootstrap, so it should work fine. Sorry, I am noobie.

Comment: do you have any live demo or fiddle so i can have a look, it seems like some other css is overwriting this one

Comment: @Kateryna I have updated the answer it should works for you, if not you better share some live demo

Answer (score 0):

Set the `width` property in your image.

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/1920x1080" alt="Carousel image" class="img-responsive" width="100%" />
```

> Note: `width="100%"` isn't W3C valid. But it work almost all modern or
>   old browser.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1920x1080" alt="..." class="img-responsive" width="100%" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1920x1080" alt="..." class="img-responsive" width="100%" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1920x1080" alt="..." class="img-responsive" width="100%" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can try this.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer, I have tried all solutions, that were posted here, but 
col-xs-12 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 worked for me, so I added col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 to my previous markup.